# Overwrite valueChanged pyqt5 adding Qt.QueuedConnection

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create my own class of QSpinBox and overwriting the valueChanged method to behaviour as I need adding the `Qt.QueuedConnection` type instead of `Qt.AutoConnection`

here is the code I use :

```
class AbstractSpinBox(QtWidgets.QSpinBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AbstractSpinBox, self).__init__(parent)

    def valueChanged(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbstractSpinBox, self).valueChanged(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I achieve that ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to extend `QSpinBox` for that? It's a signal, and you'll select the connection type when *connecting* it, not when defining it.

Comment: I have a much bigger program and I want to do this, is it possible ?

Comment: Ok Thank you very much.